# Does a nested class have access to its owner's private variables?

Tags: c++, variables

This is blowing my mind. I will post code if I need to, only if the answer is "No, it shouldn't do that."

The question is simple:

**Should a class nested inside an "owning" class (for lack of a better word) be able to access the owning class's private variables via its own pointer to an instance of the owning class?**

Because that is what I am seeing; I am using 2011 version of C++. Is this expected?

Comment: "should" as in class design or "does" as in what does the Standard say?

Comment: "should" as in does the Standard allow this?

Comment: See this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687544/question-about-c-inner-class - seems like the standard for C++ 0x flip-flopped on it, could be related to the specific version of your compiler

Comment: Classes don't "own" anything. Only *objects* do.

Comment: @RonDahlgren perfect, that indeed suggests that what I'm seeing is completely correct. I was reading the `Thinking in C++` book which made no mention of this functionality, and in fact suggested that this should not happen and you must explicitly use `friend`. Probably since it is brand new behavior in the language.

Comment: @KerrekSB A simple google search reveals a wide range of books and academic papers that use the language of a "class owning" something. It's just semantics; I think everyone knows what is meant.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: You're misrepresenting those sources. If anything, then the authors mean that "objects of this type own things". That's very different from what you appear to be thinking.

Comment: @KerrekSB My thinking is exactly what you suggest, but my language conforms to a common vernacular. It is just easy to say a "class owns an instance variable" even though nearly everyone knows that, in practice, it is the object, not the class, that actually does anything. It merely rolls off the tongue that way, just as is commonly worded in books and articles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from C++ standard N3485 `class.access.nested`:

> A nested class is a member `type` and as such has the same access rights as any other member. The members of
>   an enclosing class have no special access to members of a nested class; the usual access rules (Clause 11)
>   shall be obeyed

```
class E {
    int x;
    class B { };
    class I {
       B b; // OK: E::I can access E::B
       int y;
       void f(E* p, int i) {
          p->x = i; // OK: E::I can access E::x
       }
   };
   int g(I* p) {
      return p->y; // error: I::y is private
   }
};
```

You can find information about Clause 11 here:
[C++ Standard papers N3485](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/N3485.pdf)(need to view the file through the link or download it)

Comment: To be clear what the standard is saying: A nested class is a member *type*.

Answer (score 0):

The variables defined in the owner class, are private in its scope: i.e. Anything within that scope including the nested class can access them. If this is not your desired behavior then move the definition of the nested class outside of the owner class