# Using a C++ public variable in the outer class from inside a nested, private class

Tags: c++, qt, class

I have been handed some code that uses a nested class thus:

```
class outer : public YetAnotherObject
{
   public:
      outer();
      ~outer();

      std::string*  z;

   private:
      static outer* s_pInstance;  

      class inner : public QThread
      {
         public:
            inner() : QThread()  {}
            ~inner()  {}

         protected:
            void run()
            {
               z = "Hello, world";
               while (1)  { ... whatever ... }
            }
      }innerObj;   // <-- note edit is here
};

outer* outer::s_pInstance = 0;

outer* outer::instance(QObject* par)
{
   if (s_pInstance == 0)
   {
      s_pInstance = new outer(par);
   }

   return s_pInstance;
}
```

`z` gets set elsewhere to point to a `std::string`.

I get either compile errors or runtime crashes trying to write to `z` when calling `inner::start()`.

What is the correct way to do this?   Make `inner` inherit from `outter`?  Public or private?

---

Note:  I missed a word in my transcription  - an instance of the inner object is created at the end of its declaration, See comment indicator in the code.

Also note, rather than using the reference, I opted to use a pointer, so its, `o->z = "";`.  I couldn't recall any way to pass a self reference rather than a self pointer.

Extend the question to ask, How do I pass "this" to innerObj?

Comment: @LaszloPapp My deepest apologies.  I was farther away on this holliday than usual and did not get to check this posting.  Yes, Your answers are wonderful.   A note, where I used std::string* was to replace a far more complicated typedef/class that holds a pointer to a string.  Thought I'd save a lot of explanation that way.

Comment: I went [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687544/question-about-c-inner-class) for more insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1) You should not use a std::string pointer since it really was not meant to be used like that.

2) A nested class in C++ is independent from its outer class even if it is nested inside that. As you can see, it is the same as if it was not nested unlike in Java for instance. There is no implicit instance within the nested class, etc.

In order to access the string or any variable in the outer class, you would need to have a reference or pointer to the outter class, for instance in the following way:

```
class outer : public YetAnotherObject
{
   public:
      outer();
      ~outer();

      std::string  z; // First modification

   private:
      static outer* s_pInstance;  

      class inner : public QThread
      {
         public:
            inner(outer& o) : QThread(),  outerRef(o)  {} // Second modification
            ~inner()  {}

        outer& outerRef; // Third modification

         protected:
            void run()
            {
               z = "Hello, world";
               while (1)  { ... whatever ... }
            }
      };
};

outer* outer::s_pInstance = 0;

outer* outer::instance(QObject* par)
{
   if (s_pInstance == 0)
   {
      s_pInstance = new outer(par);
   }

   return s_pInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to the inner class a pointer or a reference to the outer class.

```
class inner : public QThread
  {
     public:
        inner(outer *o) : QThread(), o(o)  { }
        ~inner()  {}

     protected:
        void run()
        {
           o->z = "Hello, world";
           while (1)  { ... whatever ... }
        }

     private:
        outer *o;
  };
```

Though you can't assign a literal ("Hello, world") to a pointer to std::string.

**EDIT:**

Changed reference to pointer in the code above as you wish, though you can always get self reference with `*this`.

If you want to instantiate inner you can do it like this:

```
class outer : public YetAnotherObject
{
   public:
      outer() : innerObj(this) { ... }
      ~outer();

      std::string*  z;

   private:
      static outer* s_pInstance;  

      class inner : public QThread
      {
          ...
      }innerObj;
};
```

Comment: it's because in the outer class `z = "";` wouldn't work neither

Comment: why do you use a pointer to string anyway? why not simply `std::string z;`?

Comment: See the notes and edits applied to the original question.  Thanks.

Comment: @WesMiller I modified my answer according to your notes.